# Does Minecraft use a lot of data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How many gigs of internet does it cost to download Minecraft on my PC. I only have seventy gigs, so I am afraid it will use them all.

Comment: I can definitely assure you it isn't anywhere near 70Gb.

Comment: does that mean more or less than seventy

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and say very much less.

Comment: I guess the comment could have been taken either way, but I meant less.

Comment: While downloading the game has already been explained you should keep in mind that playing the game eats some traffic as well. Especially Multiplayer games will keep talking to the big white cloud.

Comment: @dly It only uses up network bandwidth if you're playing online multiplayer. You should be able to play just fine in a singleplayer world without using any data at all.

Comment: and every game launch

Comment: @dly That's a handful of kb at most and even then it isn't required, at least not after the first login. I know for a fact I've played singleplayer Minecraft before when I was in the middle of nowhere with zero internet connectivity. (Unless somehting's changed in the last year that I don't know about.)

Answer (score 3):

The installer is 2.2 MB. After the game is installed the size of the launcher's directory is ~146 MB (~141MB of this is in the `runtime` folder).

The actual game files are downloaded and stored separately from the launcher. The size of the actual game will vary depending on what versions you have downloaded, as the launcher has the capability to play older versions of Minecraft. The total size of the `.minecraft` folder (where the game is actually stored) excluding the `versions` and `assets\indexes` folders is ~148MB (~132MB of this is inside `assets\objects`).

I exclude the `versions` and `assets\indexes` folders as these are the folders whose sizes will vary depending on which and how many versions of Minecraft you have downloaded. Looking at versions 1.11 and 1.10.2:

- 1.10.2

  - `versions` = ~8.46MB
  - `assets\indexes` = ~143KB
- 1.11

  - `versions` = ~8.77MB
  - `assets\indexes` = ~154KB

So the `.minecraft` folder with versions 1.10.2 and 1.11 downloaded would be about ~165MB. As I have said, this size can vary depending on which versions you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the installer, 1.10.2 is just about 200MB. (0.2GB)

Comment: this is incorrect. the downloaded installer (from the offical site) is only about 2MB, the launcher is about 140MB and the game is about 150MB depending on versions